# How do I access LastPass Passwords on iOS/iPadOS from web browser?

Tags: password, web-browser, ipados, ios

Unlike macOS, there are no browser extensions to integrate LastPass on iOS or iPadOS in the web browser.

Although I've installed the LastPass app on my iPhone & iPad, How do I access my passwords from a web browser?!?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Chrome Users**:  [Please note that LastPass has problems in iOS/iPadOS and as of 13.3.1, the fault is still present](https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=347785&start=10). All is not lost however as LastPass in the below example is tested and known to work correctly with Firefox as of iOS/iPadOS 13.3.1.

## iOS/iPadOS Settings

1. Open Settings
2. Choose Passwords & Accounts
3. Select AutoFill Passwords
4. Check the box next to LastPass
5. Uncheck the box next to iCloud Keychain.

[image: Screenshot1]

## LastPass App

Before you can access any passwords, you must have the LasstPass app installed on your iPhone/iPad and be logged-into the App with your LastPass Master Password

[image: Screenshot2]

## Web Browser

Although this example uses Firefox, the process is almost the same for Chrome users.

### Step 1

1. Select the password field.
2. Open the share dialog by tapping on the 3 dots (*Chrome users tap the share icon*).
3. Choose "Share Page With..." *I did say the process was counter-intuitive...*

[image: Screenshot3]

### Step 2

Tap LastPass

[image: Screenshot4]

### Step 3

Tap the password offered in the LastPass dialog.

That's it.

[image: Screenshot5]

## Conclusion

Although not a very intuitive process, using LastPass with a browser on iOS/iPadOS it's still pretty easy to use.

Comment: Part of why this is so complicated is because you are not using Safari, in Safari all you would do is click the password field and it will either offer an account or show you the word Passwords, clicking this opens a modal dialog where you can pick a password from LastPass, 1Password or any other supported application. From here it autofills, no need to be logged in already, or share the page.

Comment: @unknowndomain The behavior you mention is available in other iOS browsers as well, at least with 1Password. And LastPass should support it as well, otherwise the app wouldn't show up in the first screenshot. So it might just be a bug right now which requires the workaround.

Comment: Quite possibly as I was unable to get it to work in other browsers I tested which seemed strange as the password complete works outside just browsers anyway.

Comment: The process seems to have improved drastically somewhat recently (at least using Firefox anyways). It was a bit difficult to understand how to set it up but once I did so I can use the "Password"-button provided by Firefox/keyboard. This page talks about how to do this for iphone but it's same for ipad: https://www.lastpass.com/features/autofill/iphone